# How to make a topic public to all users in django?

Tags: python, django

**There is problem**

I am creating a project, where you can make topics, that can be private or public to unauthenticated users. In every topic, you can then make several entries, applying to that topic. Now I'm trying to make a checkbox in my new_topic.html, where if you check it, it evaluates to True, if not, to False
But I can't see the topic without logging in

**What I want**

I would like to show public subjects to users who have not logged in by changing the public property to True in the view, but I do not know how to implement them

**What I've tried**

I played with the query set topic.public == True
but I don't know how to use that

**The Code**

My /learning_logs/modles.py looks like this:

```html
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Topic(models.Model):
    """topic은 사용자가 공부하고 있는 주제이다."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False) 

    def __str__(self):
        """모델에 관한 정보를 문자열 형태로 변환한다."""
        return self.text

class Entry(models.Model):
    """주제에 관해 공부한 내용"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """모델에 관한 정보를 문자열 형태로 반환한다."""
        if self.text[:] > self.text[:50]:
            return self.text[:50] + "..."
        else:
            return self.text[:]
```

My /learning_logs/views.py looks like this:

```html
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse


from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


from .models import Topic, Entry
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm

def index(request):
    """학습 로그 홈페이지"""
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

@login_required
def topics(request):
    """주제를 표시한다."""
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

@login_required
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """주제 하나와 연결된 모든 항목을 표시한다."""
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    # 주제가 현재 사용자의 것인지 확인한다.
    check_user = check_topic_owner(request, topic)

    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)


@login_required
def new_topic(request):
    """새 주제 추가"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # 들어온 데이터가 없을 때는 새 폼을 만든다.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        # POST 데이터를 받아서 처리한다.
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_topic = form.save(commit=False)
            new_topic.owner = request.user
            new_topic.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_topic.html', context)

@login_required
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """특정 주제에 관한 새 항목을 추가"""
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    check_user = check_topic_owner(request, topic)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # 전송된 데이터가 없으므로 빈 폼을 만든다.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # 받은 POST 데이터를 처리한다.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                        args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic':topic, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)

@login_required
def edit_entry(request, entry_id):
    """기존 항목을 편집한다."""
    entry = get_object_or_404(Entry, id=entry_id)
    topic = entry.topic
    check_user = check_topic_owner(request, topic)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # 첫 요청이므로 폼을 현재 텍스트로 채운다.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry)
    else:
        # POST 데이터를 받았으므로 받은 데이터를 처리한다.
        form = EntryForm(instance=entry, data=request.POST)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                    args=[topic.id]))

    context = {'entry': entry, 'topic':topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_entry.html', context)


def check_topic_owner(request, topic):
    """현재 유저가 올바른 유저인지 체크한다"""
    if topic.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404
```

My /learning_logs/forms.py looks like this

```html
from django import forms

from .models import Topic, Entry


class TopicForm(forms. ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text', 'public']
        lavels = {'text' : '', 'public' : 'lavel for public'}

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}


class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text' : ''}
        widgets = {'text' : forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':80})}
        labels = {'text':''}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':80})}
```

My /learning_logs/templates/learning_logs/new_topic.html

```html
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block header %}
  <h2>Add a new topic:</h2>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  <form action="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}" method='post'
     class="form">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}

    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value=True id="public" />
      <label class="form-check-label">
        Make it public?
      </label>
    </div>

    {% buttons %}
      <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">add topic</button>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**Another error:**

If I delete @login_required I get the following error:

```html
Traceback:

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/learning_log/learning_logs/views.py" in topics
  31.     topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1287.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1198.             self.check_related_objects(join_info.final_field, value, join_info.opts)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in check_related_objects
  1065.                 for v in value:

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  214.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: TypeError at /topics/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable
```

**Seconde error**

I used the following code:

```html
# this should really be a method on a custom ModelManager
def _get_topics_for_user(user):
    " returns a queryset of topics the user can access "
    q = Q(public=True)
    # if django < 1.10 you want "user.is_authenticated()" (with parens)
    if user.is_authenticated:
       # adds user's own private topics to the query
       q = q | Q(private=True, owner=user)

    return Topic.objects.filter(q)


def topics(request):
    topics = _get_topics_for_user(request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    topics = _get_topics_for_user(request.user)
    # here we're passing the filtered queryset, so
    # if the topic "topic_id" is private and the user is either
    # anonymous or not the topic owner, it will raise a 404
    topic = get_object_or_404(topics, id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

```html
Traceback:

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/learning_log/learning_logs/views.py" in topics
  31.     topics = _get_topics_for_user(request.user).order_by('date_added')

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/learning_log/learning_logs/views.py" in _get_topics_for_user
  27.     return Topic.objects.filter(q)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1281.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1281.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1287.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1164.         lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1028.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())

File "/mnt/c/Users/heoje/Desktop/linked/choco/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in names_to_path
  1389.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /topics/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'private' into field. Choices are: date_added, entry, id, owner, owner_id, public, text
```

Comment: because your views for showing list of topics and a single topic has `@login_required` decorator

Comment: Is there a way to solve it without getting rid of it?

Comment: you want to show list of public topics and entries for a public topic to un-logged in users right. Showing list of topics and entries for a topic is handled by views `def topics` and `def topic` respectively. So in these function you need to check if the user is logged in or not first. Then show relevant items accordingly. Correct me if I understood your question wrong.

Comment: I want to allow other users to access public topics and not access topics that are not public and When I delete @login_required, the browser displays an 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable error

Comment: I see you got two answers already, let me know if they worked for you or not. If not then I will post my answer and it will work. @bruno desthuilliers answers seems pretty accurate, it should work.

Comment: His code is certainly helpful, but again an error has occurred

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `login_required` decorator, remover the line `@login_required` above the view you want to be accessed publicly.

This [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator is used to ensure that the view is accessed by an authenticated user only.

Use this only when you want that the view should be used by an authenticated user.

You are getting this error because in line `Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user)` the `request.user` is `AnonymousUser`.

If render only if topic is public, you can check it with `topic.public` it return true or false, code may be like -

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """주제 하나와 연결된 모든 항목을 표시한다."""
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    # 주제가 현재 사용자의 것인지 확인한다.
    if topic.public:   
        check_user = check_topic_owner(request, topic)
        entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
        context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
        return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('access_dennined'))
```

Use `@login_required` if required.

Comment: I want to allow other users to access public topics and not access topics that are not public and When I delete @login_required, the browser displays an 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable error

Comment: Thank you for helping me but it did not work the way I wanted
Currently, pages that show topics in my project do not show public topics to users who are not logged in and who are not related to the public topics
I want to make the public topics exposed and the private topics not visible

Answer (score 0):

You first have to remove the `login_required` decorator from the  `topics` and `topic` views, obviously - the goal of this decorator, as the name implies, being to force users to log in.

Then you have to change your views code to handle both cases - anonymous and logged in users. Assuming that you want everyone to see public topics and only topics owners to access private topics, this might look like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

# this should really be a method on a custom ModelManager
def _get_topics_for_user(user):
    " returns a queryset of topics the user can access "
    q = Q(public=True)
    # if django < 1.10 you want "user.is_authenticated()" (with parens)
    if user.is_authenticated:
       # adds user's own private topics to the query
       q = q | Q(public=False, owner=user)

    return Topic.objects.filter(q)


def topics(request):
    topics = _get_topics_for_user(request.user).order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    topics = _get_topics_for_user(request.user)
    # here we're passing the filtered queryset, so
    # if the topic "topic_id" is private and the user is either
    # anonymous or not the topic owner, it will raise a 404 
    topic = get_object_or_404(topics, id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Comment: I used your code but the browser displays an error I will attach a Traceback to the text.

Comment: @JeonghoHeo I'll have a look at it but let's make things clear: the code I posted is merely an example to get you started, if what you expect is that I write your app for you then bad luck, that's not how it works. And you really have to learn debugging by yourself (and learn how django works too).

Comment: @JeonghoHeo : ok, seen your traceback. There was indeed a small error in my example code, but really, can't you read the traceback and find the error by yourself ? It took me 2 seconds to spot it and 1 second to fix it.  If you can't even debug such a trivial problem by yourself you're not going to succeed with your project, really...

Comment: ah I see Thank you okay I'll take a closer look at them When I solve it, I will leave a message

Comment: Hello I saw your code and good working so Thank you but I had another problem When I created a new topic, I checked the public checkbox and created a topic, but which is not visible public topics to other users or users who are not logged in. I am guessing there is a problem with the checkbox or new_topic.html

Comment: As I already stated, I'm not going to write your project for you. Django has a good documentation and quite some debugging and testing tools, so use them.

Answer (score 0):

I also come to this practice of laster chapter20, still no got any idea of this. Hope you success @Jeongho Heo about the latest issue you mention above, the requested topic is all creat by exist user, but there havn't define any topic objects that anonymousUser can access, advice you can creat two class, 1st' topic class can return public topic, 2nd topic class return topic of login user, and extend 2nd object from 1st object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).